# kafka foreing key join with last record

Tags: java, apache-spark, stream, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

i have 2 stream both have the same Type on the key and on the value,

```
  - first represent a finantial instrument with key (string) Currency (Eur-USD)
  - second represent a finantial instrument with key (tenor) Eur-3month , Eur-6month , USD-3month


  - first stream: <key, value> = <Eur , { data , .... } >
  - second stream: <key, value> = <Eur-3month , { data .... }>
```

the requirement is that the last of one stream must join the other stream always with the last key received depending on the (month: 3m, 6m, 7m)

```
   - i thought that the streams must be K-tables is this the correct way to join them and have in output always the last join on the last updates ? 
   - i can have the same results with a stream ?
```

in this statement i have found that the most similar thing i can use is

```
   KStream<K, RV> join(final GlobalKTable<GK, GV> globalKTable,
                                 final KeyValueMapper<? super K, ? super V, ? extends GK> keyValueMapper,
                                 final ValueJoiner<? super V, ? super GV, ? extends RV> joiner)
```

Using the KeyValueMapper i could join the keys
but on the left side i have a stream and not a k-table and this will not update the join on "updates" of the left side

Answer (score 0):

Typically you choose the smaller of the streams (the one with fewer distinct keys) and materialize it into a KTable either by just reading it from kafka as a table (KStreamBuilder.table()) or by using .groupByKey() followed by reduce() or aggregate().

Then you join your other stream with that KTable.

Alternatively, you can materialize both your streams into KTables and join them. I didn't exactly understand your use case in detail, hence cannot advise which is better.

See: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Join+Semantics

Comment: the problem is similar to this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-99%3A+Add+Global+Tables+to+Kafka+Streams   but ktable-ktable   , yes you did not get the problem

Comment: If you partition both your topics by the currency code, then you don't need to use GlobalKTables. You get more join options using normal KTables.

Comment: The problem is not around GlobalKtables, the problem is to have a foreign key , in one table we have a K  and in another K-K'  and i want join k = k